# How do you debug what a button does on a website?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

For instance, let's say we have this website for downloading a tool called Aptana,

http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download

at the bottom of that page, there's a big blue button that says something to the effect "Download".  But when you right click that button and choose copy address, and paste it, you see that it isn't a simple html link because it just leads to the current URL plus the pound sign.  Something is happening in javascript which initiates a download from some download URL.

How can one use a debuging tool such as google chrome's dev-tools to locate where this download link is coming from?

I understand the first steps (in chrome) are to right click the button, choose

```
Inspect Element -->  Event Listeners (right pane) --> click --> main.js (link)
```

And that will show you the javascript code that is executed when the button is pressed (I think at least).  From there a button that looks like two curly braces '{}' can be pressed to make the javascript code look prettier.  But at this stage, I'm not sure what steps are taken to figure out the objective of discovering where in the code the webapp initiates the download of the direct url (which is something along the lines of ).

by sheer luck while debuggnig and stepping over code at random, I found line 289 which reads

```
if (Q) {
     for (var a, b = 0; a = Q[b++]; )
         a.call(s, c);
     Q = null
}
```

and when I mouseover the letter a in the expression `a.call(s,c);` a popup displays the http link to the direct download.

```
function (){
    document.location = "http://download.aptana.com/studio3/standalone/3.4.0/linux/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_3.4.0.zip";
}
```

What is the professional way of getting to the bottom of things here?  Are there framework/ library markers that should be identified?  Are there any theories as to how one should step through unfamiliar code like this?  And are there any shortcuts that I could have used to aid me but missed?  I'm starting to think that the phrase 'document.location' was something I should have just known to start looking for.  How would one search for references to such 'instructions'?

Comment: I'm noticing that the `document.location` line came from the response packet I get from doing `$("#aptana_download_form").submit();` so I wouldn't have been able to search the source documents for that snippet.  I found this out by using the network tab in chrome's web-tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before clicking the button, open the Web Inspector and go to the Sources panel. Press the [image: Pause] button and then click the download button. The JavaScript debugger will break on the event handler. Step through the code until you get to the actual handler:

```
// submit download form
$(".submit-aptana-download-form").click(function(){
  $("#aptana_download_form").submit();
  return false;
});
```

Voila.

As for frameworks, from looking at the names once you get into the debugger, I can tell it uses jQuery. You can probably use similar heuristics.

Comment: I see it.  That's a lot of code to step into before you get to that anonymous function.  Why is there so much code it goes through before it gets there.  Oh, I see that's jQuery I'm stepping through, that's good if it's the type of thing that's easy to recognize later on (if only it wasn't the minimized version, it might be more obvious).